# Solve Matrix Equation $\sqrt{x^TAx} - x^\top\theta = 0$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

let $x,\theta \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ Positive semi-definite and symmetrtic. How to solve (for $x \neq 0$) the following equation?

$$\sqrt{x^TAx} - x^\top\theta = 0$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit](http://goo.gl/mLWc8) the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Trivial solution $x=0$

Comment: What can you say about the eigen values of a real positive semi-definite symmetric matrix? How did you define $|x|$?

Comment: Thanks @Invisible for your comment. The eigenvalues of a PSD matrix are $\lambda_i \geq 0$ how this can help in solving the problem? There is no particular context to my question I was trying to understand whether this Matrix equation has a solution or under which condition it does.

Comment: Hello @Andrei thanks for your comment. I edited the question and excluded the trivial solution $x=0$. What can we say about the other solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation can have an infinity of solutions. Try a simple trivial case. Choose $n=2$ and $A=I_2$. Then the general form of $x^T$ is $(x_1\ x_2)$. So the equation becomes $$\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}-x_1\theta_1-x_2\theta_2=0$$
Moving the last two terms from the left to the right, and squaring the equation, you get:
$$x_1^2+x_2^2=x_1^2\theta_1^2+x_2^2\theta_2^2+2x_1x_2\theta_1\theta_2$$
This is the equation of a conic (degenerate). In this case any point on the conic is a solution. Simpler way to see that, if $x$ is a solution, $ax$ is a solution as well, with $a>0$,

Comment: An even more trivial case is $A=O$, $\theta=0$.

Comment: That is indeed trivial :)